# Drools Workbench Exception: cannot open git-upload-pack

Tags: git, drools, kie-workbench

When deploying Drools Workbench 6.5 **(kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-eap7.war)** on JBOSS EAP, getting following error:

```
xception: https://github.com/guvnorngtestuser1/guvnorng-playground.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
```

Since i am behind a firewall which doesn't allow downloading from Github, how can i bypass this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future people:
run JBOSS EAP with parameter `-Dorg.kie.demo=false`:

`standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml -Dorg.kie.demo=false`

Comment: I deployed to tomcat and added '-Dorg.kie.demo=false' to vm options. It solved my problem.